# how to apply filter on field using multiple values in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a model that contain field `state` type of enum and accept only three values

```
active
disabled
deleted
```

and currently am filtering to get all the active ones by

```
const query = {state : "active" ... other filters here}
const posts = await post.find(query)
```

but I have a case where I need to get the posts that have stated both `active` and `disabled` and I searched in mongoose docs for something I can use but I find nothing at the moment i want something clean that achieve this code

```
const query1 = {state : "active" ... other filters here}
const posts1 = await post.find(query1)

const query2 = {state : "disabled" ... other filters here}
const posts2 = await post.find(query2)

const posts = {...posts1, ...posts2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const query = { state: { $in: [ "active", "disabled"] } }
const posts = await post.find(query)
```

This will result in a list of posts whose state is either `active` or `disabled`.

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field
> equals any value in the specified array. To specify an $in expression,
> use the following prototype:

From [MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).